# How to print more than 2 words ? nextLine() causes an error if I had another user input above it

Tags: java, string

This is my code:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);        
    int a = kb.nextInt();
    String word = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hello");        
    System.out.println("World");
    System.out.println(word);
```

The result is:

```
123
Hello
World
```

123 is my input for integer, but it didn't ask for any input for my **word** variable. Different case for **.next()**. It works but It can only print 1 word instead of 2+ if I put more than 2 words in my **String word** variable.

Comment: Did you try to use `while` loop? `while (kb.hasNext()) {     }`.

Comment: Use 123 231. Here, "123" goes to "a" and "231" goes to word

Comment: @dmitryro Not yet. How does the hasNext() work ?

Comment: @ShaunakPatel My apologies for the misstyped in my question. It works when I put my nextLine() above my nextLine() but It wont work if I put my nextInt() above my nextLine(). (Saying that the first input must be an integer)